# Multiple thread access(read/write) same table

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

If there are multiple thread which access (read/write) to a same table into a DB, what considerations of thread-safety should I take?

Comment: What is the actual question? Is there a threading problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some good tips, for example if using MySQL

- Use row-level locking.
- Use the TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED isolation level.
- Avoid queries that cannot use indexes; they require locking of all the rows in the table (if only very briefly) and might block an update.
- Avoid sharing Statements among threads

Here is some more [information and reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html)

Answer (score 1):

check for mechanisms which implement transactions in different isolation levels. These mechanism are present in database system or your API.